# A dictionary of dictionary, which contains values in form of list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary of dictionary, which contains values as a list. I do not know how to access these values one by one

I don't know how to access these values one after the other, so really have not tried any method.

```
my_dictionary = {0: {'question': [1,2,3,4], 'answer': 0},
                 1: {'question': [5,6,7,8], 'answer': 0}
                }

my_question_list = [5,9,4,3]
```

I want to compare every element in my_question_list with every element in key "question" of 0th key of my_dictionary.

I simply don't know how to access those values stored in a dictionary of dictionary, and then compare it with the elements of the list.

Comment: `my_dictionary[0]['question']` is the first list. `my_dictionary[0]['question'][0]` is the first element of that list. If you dict will always have ordered numeric keys, you might as well use a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the first dictionary (with `0` key) in `my_dictionary` , using `my_dictionary[0]`.

You can also access the value of the  `question` key, using 
`my_dictionary[0]['question']`.

You can access the first element of the array by using `my_dictionary[0]['question'][0]`.